# I can't handle to resolve and reject methoods on JS promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

```
const selector = document.getElementById('input')
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
const flag = document.getElementById('content')

const API = 'https://restcountries.com/v2/all'
const arr = []
let found = false

fetch(API).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
    data.forEach(el => {
        arr.push(el.name)
    })
    console.log(arr)
})


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let info = selector.value
    let reg = new RegExp(info, 'gi')
    let p1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fetch(API).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                if (reg.test(element.name)) {
                    flag.style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.flag})`;
                    flag.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'
                    flag.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
                    found = true
                }
            })
        })
        if (found) {
            res('nice')
        }
        else {
            rej('so bad')
        }
    })
    p1.then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

I'm trying to get data with fetch and output flags with using input:text value. but I want to make an error on console if user enter wrong words. I tried that with using promise but if user enter right and wrong both , it doesnt matter. rej methood always work. how can I solve that ?

Comment: Long story short: you are evaluating `if (found)` long before your `fetch` is finished ...

Comment: Apart from the problem explained in the duplicate question and in the comment above, another problem in your code is the unnecessary use of the `Promise` constructor inside the click event listener. `fetch` already returns a promise, you no need to wrap it in a `Promise` constructor.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!